# Problema con eventos Java

Tags: java, eventos

Desarrollé una aplicación para marcado de entrada y salida utilizando un lector biometrico, el problema es que el lector se activa con el método formWindowOpened,
donde llamo a  Captura() que  es con el que identifico la Huella este método se llama a si mismo esperando que se genere una marca de Entrada, el problema es que tengo un Botón (Salir), pero cuando Hago click sobre este no realiza la acción que debe, debido a que el sistema sigue ejecutando Captura, y no puedo Cerrar la aplicacion, porque esta bloquada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: Este es el JFrame]

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo?
¿se podra con Hilos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entendí `Captura()` genera un bucle infinito sobre el thread principal, por lo que no se puede ejecutar al método `Salir()`. La manera mas optima se trataría de tener un thread sobre `Captura()` para que así se ejecute en segundo plano y poder atender a las peticiones sobre el hilo principal.

```
private Thread tCaptura;

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

    // Se instancia tCaptura
    if (tCaptura == null) {
        tCaptura = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Captura();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Se verifica que tCaptura este libre para poder leer y no crear un
     * thread hasta que se termina de leer el anterior acceso.
     */
    if (!tCaptura.isAlive()) {
        tCaptura.start();
    }
}
```